# JButton not removing properly

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a JPanel that contains a JButton with an ActionListener. After a certain number of clicks, the JButton needs to be removed. However, when I call remove() on it, i get a pressed button that won't go away.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class SetuPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField user = new JTextField();
   private JLabel label = new JLabel();
   private JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
   private int phase = 0;
   public SetuPanel() {
      super(new FlowLayout());
      user.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,22));
      submit.addActionListener(new Submit());
      label.setText("Enter Desired Username:");
      add(label);
      add(user);
      add(submit);
   }
   private void remov(JComponent jc) {
      remove(jc);
      validate();
   }
   private class Submit implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println(user.getText());
         if (phase == 2) {
            phase++;
            label.setText("Playing!");
            remov(submit);
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: 1) Use a `CardLayout`. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6):

- call `submit.setVisible(false)` (rather) in the case that you'll needed this `JButton` again visible on the screen,
- you have to call to container `revalidate()` and  `repaint()`
- `JPanel` is not accesible directly because you call `class extends JPanel`, then you have to call

.

```
remove(jc);
revalidate();
repaint()
```

Comment: I tried that. I still get the same problem. Even with submit.setVisible(false)

Comment: Could it be because the ActionListener is bound to submit?

Comment: whats happened when you to call this.relidate and this.repaint

Comment: The guy is right, when you remove a component from a JPanel you need to call the .validate() method. You may also call repaint() as well after.

Comment: I still get the same problem. I can find no discernable reason as to why the button wouldn't disappear. On a side note, it is the same error that occurs if I try and debug the panel and then click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are editing it in code you didn't post, `phase` is only being incremented inside the if block. Therefore, `phase` will never become 2. Do you want to be incrementing `phase` every time the `ActionListener` is called?

Comment: It is being incremented, i cut out that code because I felt it wasn't relavent

Answer (score 1):

The `repaint()` method is automatically called(by the repaint manager) on the screen only in case of resizing/relocating/changing the layout of a panel. If you add a component then it does not get displayed on its own. You'll have to explicitly call the `repaint()`/`revalidate()` methods to ensure that the component appears on the screen. There is nothing wrong with this.

I suggest that you do this:
To remove:

```
JPanel.remove(component); // Remove component from your JPanel
JPanel.revalidate();
JPanel.repaint(); // Repaint a JPanel
```

To add:

```
JPanel.add(component); // Add component to JPanel
JPanel.revalidate();
JPanel.repaint(); // Repaint a JPanel
```

You must put `this` instead of `JPanel` to work in your case.